# Adding class getattr behaviour to pydantic v2 BaseModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, pydantic

I have a library that is essentially a type of ORM. As part of this I have a my own 'Model' class that is to be subclassed by end users of the library to create models that are to be persisted in a nosql database.

My base model class inherits from `pydantic.BaseModel`. One of the features of this library is that you can create filters to be used for database queries with relatively simple syntax.

For example, say I have my own class `base.Model` and a user creates a model like this:

```
class Person(base.Model):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    age: int
```

It should then be possible to construct a filter object by doing something like this:

```
filter_ = (Person.age > 10) & (Person.first_name == "Bill")
```

In pydantic V1, I did this by adding a metaclass like this:

```
class Model(pydantic.BaseModel, metaclass=utils.MetaGetFilterPydantic):
    ...
```

where

```
class MetaGetFilterPydantic(MetaGetFilter, type(pydantic.BaseModel)):
    pass
```

and finally

```
class MetaGetFilter(type):
    def _get_full_annotations(cls) -> collections.ChainMap[str, Any]:
        annotations_ = [cls.__annotations__]
        for parent in cls.__mro__:
            if parent is pydantic.BaseModel:
                break

            annotations_.append(parent.__annotations__)

        return collections.ChainMap(*annotations_)

    def __getattr__(cls, item: str) -> MyFilterObject:
        if item not in cls._get_full_annotations():
            raise AttributeError(f"type object '{cls.__name__}' has no attribute '{item}'")

        return MyFilterObject(...)
```

This allowed the normal attribute lookup to function while also allowing me to return a filter object that can be used to construct the filter if the user tries to access an attribute on the class directly that is also set in the annotations.

Now, the issue is that in pydantic V2, this break completely. I seen that pydantic V2 uses `pydantic._internal._model_construction.ModelMetaclass` as a metaclass to create new models, and I've played around with letting this my metaclass be a subclass of this and overwriting its `__getattr__`.

If I do something like this on my metaclass (after subclassing the pydantic model metaclass above):

```
def __getattr__(cls, item):
    try:
        return super().__getattr__(item)
    except AttributeError:
        if not cls.__pydantic_complete__ or cls is base.Model:
            raise

        attrs = (
            cls._get_full_annotations()  
        )
        if item not in attrs:
            raise

        return MyFilterObject(...)
```

it will work for one single level of subclassing of my own model, but will break for any further subclassing of my model since then my check will not work.

Long rant to basically ask, is there any safe way to add behaviour to pydantic class object access in V2? It seems like pydantic now relies on `__getattr__` raising an `AttributeError`

I've thought about there potentially being a way to know when the object is actually initialized, but `__pydantic_complete__` did not seem to be enough